# ELM327 Bluetooth communication issue

Tags: android, bluetooth, elm327

I made an Android app to communicate with an ELM327 OBD-II dongle via bluetooth. 
When I test the app with a bluetooth serial terminal (CoolTerm / macOS) the app is **receiving and sending** data without an issue.

Using my app to transfer commands to the ELM will result in broken and splitted answers.

Output:

```
DataReceivedHandler: 9V
DataReceivedHandler: 9V>
DataReceivedHandler: 11.
DataReceivedHandler: 9V>
```

[image: Screenshot]

The example above should show the result of the `AT RV` command which queries the battery's voltage of the vehicle (I sent the command multiple times).

Expected (good) result should look like this: `>11.9V`

Before I send the first command to query OBD values the ELM is initialized by these AT-commands:

```
AT D
AT Z
AT E0
AT L0
AT S0
AT H0
AT SP 0
```

If you have any idea how to get clear answers from the ELM, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems everything is ok, but you read and show only part of the data buffer. Please add source code of communication part to clarify issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution..

The terminal program was sending `\n` and the ELM sends `\r` for the termination of the statement.